# Netlogo: sequence of numbers with repeated elements

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to ask Netlogo to generate a sequence of numbers with repeated elements, e.g.

```
[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]
```

I tried to use the `n-values N [i -> i]` syntax but it just gives a sequential list of numbers, 0 to N.

So far, I have tried using `n-values` primitive with `sentence`, e.g.

```
let mylist ( list sentence
  n-values 3 [1] sentence
  n-values 3 [2]
  n-values 3 [3]
)
```

The problem is that this still returns a list of lists (i.e. `[[1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]]`) and this causes problems for me later when trying to add this list into a matrix.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you want to describe the list to be created and is the sequence independent of the repetitions? For example, do you want something like input (2,4) to generate [ 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ]? Or are you wanting input 3 to produce [ 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3] and input 2 to produce [ 1 1 2 2 ]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
reduce sentence (map [x -> n-values 3 [x]] (range 1 4))
```